# Firefox not working with my own DNS server, but everything else does

Tags: linux, firefox, vpn, dns, tailscale

I've recently setup a [CoreDNS](https://coredns.io/) server on my "local" tailscale VPN network. Chrome, `dig`, `nslookup`, and everything else works with the correct DNS server being queried (I've double checked using wireshark), but for some reason Firefox queries `127.0.0.1` instead of the IP of the DNS server (let's call it `1.2.3.4`).

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome and I've installed `resolvconf.service` with the following `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/resolv.conf` contents:

```
nameserver 1.2.3.4
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Disabling DoH
2. Clearing Firefox's DNS cache
3. Updating and reinstalling Firefox

I'm not entirely sure why:

1. Firefox queries 127.0.0.1 while other tools query `1.2.3.4`
2. Even if it queries `127.0.0.1`, why `systemd-resolved` doesn't redirect/point the query to `1.2.3.4`

Comment: as a matter of interest, what's listening to UDP 127.0.0.1:53 ?

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

You have to have these lines on your `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` (where `1.2.3.4` is your own DNS server and `1.1.1.1` is a fallback)

```bash
[Resolve]
DNS=1.2.3.4 1.1.1.1
DNSStubListener=yes
DNSStubListenerExtra=udp:127.0.0.1:53
```

#### Explanation

Firefox (at least right now) queries `127.0.0.1:53` whereas `systemd-resolved` listens on `127.0.0.53:53`. The `DNSStubListenerExtra` line on the config file above will make `systemd-resolved` also listen on `127.0.0.1:53`.

You can also use `iptables` to redirect `127.0.0.1:53` to `127.0.0.53:53`:

```bash
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.53:53
```